# What does "Real" mean in this UML Diagram?

Tags: oop, design-patterns, uml, decorator

Is it a data-type? And what language is it?

[image: Diagram]

Comment: It's not very clear, but yes, "Real" is typically a datatype corresponding to (non-imaginary) floating-point values.

Answer (score 1):

> A real data type is a data type used in a computer program to
>   represent an approximation of a real number. Because the real numbers
>   are not countable, computers cannot represent them exactly using a
>   finite amount of information. Most often, a computer will use a
>   rational approximation to a real number.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_data_type

Real is known in SQL for example, but other languages have corresponding datatypes.

Comment: Other keywords for the same thing: Float and Double. Real and Float usually take 4 bytes while Double takes 8.

Answer (score 1):

The specification "says" : DataTypes model Types whose instances are distinguished only by their value.

It means, as I understood, each instance as indentifier (technically, for me, it could seen as the address in memory if no other identifier is available) but two instances can have the same attributes values.

For example, you can have a class Person with an attribute name.

Two different instances of Person may have the same name because they have another identifier (they are not in the same address)

For Datatype, this is not possible because the identifier is the value.

Datatype is not PrimitiveType, PrimitiveType defines a predefined DataType, without any substructure. A PrimitiveType may have an algebra and operations defined outside of UML, for example, mathematically. (see 10.5.7 of specification document)

Real is a PrimitiveType defines as (see 21.1 of specification document)
 :

An instance of Real is a value in the (infinite) set of real numbers. Typically an implementation
will internally represent Real numbers using a floating point standard such as ISO/IEC/IEEE
60559:2011 (whose content is identical to the predecessor IEEE 754 standard).

hope this helps you.